# 403 forbidden when saving post with the word "Shavings."

Tags: php, wordpress, http-status-code-403

I've come across a strange one.

Today, while trying to save posts on `WordPress`.

**Getting Error**

> 403 forbidden Access to this resource on the server is denied!

I narrowed it down to the use of the word "Shavings."

If, I remove the full stop or add a "v" or do anything to change this word, the post saves but if I use the word "Shavings.", I get a 403 forbidden error.

Has anyone ever come across an issue where certain keywords get a 403 forbidden error and know how to troubleshoot and fix such an issue?

Thanks a mill.

Comment: While I've no idea what to do to fix this, I have come across it. A similar thing happened when I saved a form with an input with a name containing the word 'having' - I guess it might have fallen foul of some SQL injection protection.

Comment: Found the solution below Ben, appears to work for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who may come across this in the future, add the following to the .htaccess file. Appears to have done the trick.

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
      SecRuleEngine Off
      SecFilterInheritance Off
      SecFilterEngine Off
      SecFilterScanPOST Off
      SecRuleRemoveById 300015 3000016 3000017
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Do you have any source for this data? What do these rule IDs stand for? Are all three needed?